# useMemo Issue with React Three-fiber when adding the Canvas

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber, react-usememo

I have the below package.json, i installed three, three/drei and three/fiber and three/postprocessing

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-three/drei": "9.14.3",
    "@react-three/fiber": "8.0.26",
    "@react-three/postprocessing": "2.4.4",
    "three": "^0.141.0"
  }
}
```

---

the current code is adding a canvas object into the react application,
Box is just a component returning a mesh element

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import Box from "./Box";
const ThreeD = () => { 
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Canvas shadows>
          <Box />
        </Canvas>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};
```

on the load of the page i got the below issue:

[error on load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRT7d.png)
I tried using the useMemo as below, but the same issue remains,

```
import React, { Suspense, useMemo } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import Box from "./Box";
const ThreeD = () => {
  const Canv = useMemo(() => {
    return (
      <Canvas>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Box />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
    );
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <Canv />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ThreeD;
```

Node version: 8.19.2

the issue is originated from the file :(react-three-fiber.esm.js:119:1) at the code : React.useMemo(() => extend(THREE), []);

Answer (score 1):

I think it can help you. You should add dependencies array in `useMemo` and use result of `useMemo` correct.

```js
import React, { Suspense, useMemo } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import Box from "./Box";

const ThreeD = () => {
  const Canv = useMemo(() => (
      <Canvas>
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
          <Box />
        </Suspense>
      </Canvas>
  ), []);
  
  return (
    <div>
      {Canv}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: i tried adding this adjustment, the issue remained the same, as if its something related to their library, because the issue is originated from the file :(react-three-fiber.esm.js:119:1) at the code : React.useMemo(() => extend(THREE), []);

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, I was installing the packages outside the main project folder